# chromedriver does not execute script, selenium test finishes with no results printed out

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code in a test helper class

```
@staticmethod
def setup_with_new_displayname():
    """ Sets the application up for tests. 'execute_script' functions had
        to be called as a workaround because issues with the webdriver ones
    """
    time.sleep(5)
    # the next line is where I have the problem:
    TestHelper.driver.execute_script(
        "document.querySelector('#displayname-input').value = 'gecó '")
    TestHelper.driver.find_element_by_id("displayname-input").send_keys(
        Keys.BACKSPACE)         #Workaround for the field to notice input

    # clicks the "Use this name" button
    time.sleep(1)           # otherwise the button is not always found
    TestHelper.driver.execute_script(
        "document.querySelector('#display-name-ok-btn').click()")
```

And I have this code that uses the one above:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    """ Get the display name prompt out of the way 
        (it is tested in test_display_name_dialog.py)
    """
    TestHelper.setup_with_new_displayname()
    time.sleep(3)
```

I use this VERY SAME seccond snippet at two places, and it works in the first case, but doesn't in the second (WTF?). The second time it opens up the page and the dialog, the focus is even on the text input, the cursor in it, but the text is not written there. (As you can see in my comments, I had problems before with the "no-execute_script" approach too).

The bash I run this from does not show any test results as it should, but is ready to take the next command, which tells me the test script is finished (well, at least it thinks so.) I even tried to print from the code as a way of debugging - no result.

Do you have any idea why this happens? And generally speaking, do you have any idea for a stabler approach for testing in Chrome? I feel I am ready to dump Webdriver, since it caused (almost) only frustration, and it's hard to see what I gained with it now.

The files are to be found here, if for some reason you would like to see more of them:
[https://github.com/thenakedthunder/flack/blob/reactify/flack/src/**test**/selenium/test_helper.py](https://github.com/thenakedthunder/flack/blob/reactify/flack/src/__test__/selenium/test_helper.py)
[https://github.com/thenakedthunder/flack/blob/reactify/flack/src/**test**/selenium/test_channel_view.py](https://github.com/thenakedthunder/flack/blob/reactify/flack/src/__test__/selenium/test_channel_view.py)

Comment: Why are you using `execute_script`? why not selenium `send_keys()` and `click()`? you commented `send_keys()` as a workaround, but this is the other way around. Using `execute_script` is a workaround.

Comment: Actually, there is anouther comment: 

    """ Sets the application up for tests. 'execute_script' functions had
        to be called as a workaround because issues with the webdriver ones

Comment: I had the very same problems with them, and I found someone in a forum like this saying that "execute_scripts" is a more reliable way... As it turned out, it's not. (I tried it out with send_keys again, only to have the very same problem with it - and at the other place I call this method, it still works...).

Is chromedriver a source of hours of frustration, googling and "stack-overflowing" for others, too, or only for me? How can in it be reliable?

Comment: You shouldn't be using execute_script for tests, because a user won't do that. execute_script is for scraping only.

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario, I will try to remember this :) Since it does not work with send_keys either, and since I had enough of wasting days (literally days) because something stopped working with chromedriver that's worked before, I deleted all selenium stuff from my project and now try to find a more predictable technology for my UI tests.

Comment: I don't think this is selenium's fault, it sounds like you followed some bad advice. Also, tests are supposed to fail sometimes (when the UI has problems)

Comment: I didn't say it's selenium, it looks like it's chromedriver. I don't know what you're aiming at, but I think there was no problem with the UI, the case worked well when tested manually. The code is being used twice, perfectly works 10/10 times from one file and just hangs up with no feedback or possibility to debug or log anything 10/10 times from the other one. The whole thing stops at the code used, not from the "client" code.

Comment: Add in that certain things work for weeks, then suddenly not, and you have to look for workarounds, taking so much time that I think I lost more time using this tool for testing than what I won with it. Sorry, but after all this I feel it's unpredictable and, for me, useless. 

For what it's worth, I know people use this (really sorry for them), and probably they got a great reason for that. I am by no way an expert of testing, I just needed a reliable and predictable tool that does what it promises, so I can test my hobby project and practice writing automated test.